# Resuming Spotify after pause on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, objective-c-blocks

I have an app that I want to be able to pause and resume the current playing song. The only way I've found so far is this:

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] pause];
// some time passes
[[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] play];
```

The problem is that if it's a 3rd party app that is playing, like Spotify, it seems to lose focus to the iOS Music.app when I do this. So when I try to resume with [ play], the last played song in Music.app starts playing.

Is there a way to pause and resume Spotify (or whatever app was playing) without losing focus to the Music.app? Aka, the exact same behaviour as pressing play/pause in iOS Action Center

Comment: did you find any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's sadly no way to do this (with public API that is, there are private API's but if you want to go in the AppStore you can't use them).